# Taking the differences in rows using head and tail functions in R

Tags: r, tail, head

I have such data

```
id Pos
1    1
2    10
3    4
4    2
5    3
6    16
```

What I want to do is take the difference between the rows of `Pos` conditional on the `id`. If `id` is an odd number, then the difference is `1-10=-9`. If `id` is an even number, the difference is `10-1=9`.

So I should get

```
difference
-9
9
2
-2
-13
13
```

I tried this

```
q <- ifelse( (id %% 1) == 0,(tail(Pos, -1) - head(Pos, -1)), (head(Pos, -1) - tail(Pos, -1)) )
```

but it worked for the odds number only.

Any idea how to do this in R?

Cheers

Günal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to create a group for each two elements with `gl`, take the `diff`erence of 'Pos', `rep`licate twice (or `n()`), and change the sign based on the odd/even `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(grp = as.integer(gl(n(), 2, n()))) %>% 
    mutate(Diff = rep(diff(Pos), n())) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-grp) %>%
    mutate(Diff =  Diff * c(1, -1)[(id %%2) + 1])
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#     id   Pos  Diff
#  <int> <int> <dbl>
#1     1     1    -9
#2     2    10     9
#3     3     4     2
#4     4     2    -2
#5     5     3   -13
#6     6    16    13
```

---

If we need a solution with `head/tail` from `base R`

```
i1 <-  with(df1, rep((tail(Pos, -1) - head(Pos, -1))[c(TRUE, FALSE)], each = 2))    
c(1, -1)[(df1$id %%2) + 1] * i1
#[1]  -9   9   2  -2 -13  13
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(id = 1:6, Pos = c(1L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 16L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. It works, but there is two more things: 
(1) My original Pos consist of 740 observations. How can I adjust your code to my data
(2) How can I extract Diff so that I can use it for calculations

Comment: @Günal. It shouldn't matter beecause the `gl` is based on the number of rows (`n()`)

Comment: @Günal. Could you pleasse apply the same code bcz it is not dependent on any other constraints except the number of rows which would be `740` for your data

Answer (score 2):

Here's a base solution:

```
i <- seq(from = 1,to = nrow(DF), by = 2)
DF$difference <- rep(DF$Pos[i] - DF$Pos[i+1], each = 2)
DF$difference[i+1] <- DF$difference[i+1] * -1

DF

  id Pos difference
1  1   1         -9
2  2  10          9
3  3   4          2
4  4   2         -2
5  5   3        -13
6  6  16         13
```